# Adblock plus blocks my html contents in Safari but not in Chrome and FF

Tags: html, iframe, browser, safari, safari-content-blocker

I am building my webpage. I installed Adblock and Adblock plus in Both chrome and Safari.

- In Chrome, it displays my content even when the **Adblocker Plus** is enabled
- But, same content when i try in Safari browser, then it does not display the content

My question is that,why Adblock Plus blocks my content in Safari, whereas the Adblock plus in chrome displays that same content.
The above issue is seen when Adblocker plus is in Enabled mode.
Please help me to get rid of this problem. I am struggling with this issue.

Thanks in Advance. :-)